# FreeBSD built-in packages

Tags: package-management, freebsd

I am trying to install/remove packages.
I use a [bento/freebsd-10.3](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/boxes/freebsd-10.3) virtualbox image to try on.

When I execute `pkg info -q`, I can see a list of installed packages.
What I am confused about is that some packages are not in the list.

for example: `ssh*`, `*ssl*` are *not in the list*.

**How to manage(remove or upgrade) i.e. these packages in `/usr/bin`, say, `/usr/bin/ssh`, `/usr/lib/libssl.so`?**

Because if I run `pkg install`, seems all files are being installed to `/usr/local`.

Comment: thank you for your details, but can you maybe phrase a question of what you really want to know?

Comment: yes, I make the question bold font now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FreeBSD has their own ssh in the **Base System (not packaged)**. Same goes for ssl.

These two components you mention are upgraded with freebsd-upgrade.

Your observation is correct that everything installed with pkg is in /usr/local. And /usr/bin and /bin etc. are reserved for the base system components.

But it's possible to install those two packages from ports / pkgng as well. I assume you didn't do that, that's why they're not visible in pkg.

So, there is no way to manage these as packages with pkg command. Especially the ssl components you don't want to delete as they are used for many things in the system.